# Reachability - 3G network - No credit

Tags: 3g, reachability

I have a slight issue and wondering if someone out there can help.
I am using reachability in my project and it is working without any issues, however we have a phone that has 3g connection but no credit and this isn't falling within the reachability criteria so not erroring at all.

Is there any way to detect this and handle it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF no credit, the behavior of network connection is up to your operator. 
You can check whether socket is broken but you will not know it is caused by no credit or, server down, or other real network connection issue.
If you operator provide some online system to check credit, maybe you can implement a function to check credit online with some delay (up to operator's system)

Comment: I don't really need to know if there is credit or not but I do need something back from the app to say that it can't connect to the internet. Reachability tells me that there is a 3G connection present and allows the app to continue. There is a 3g connection but there is no credit so no internet access

Comment: Yes, therefore, you can try to connect to server. If connection failed, you can prompt user that internet connection broken. Maybe you can give some instruction like "Please check credit" in the prompt information